# Unable to form connection ASP.NET network path

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

EDIT #1: The server is listening on port 1434 and I am looking at the TCP Port in the properties of TCP/IP Properties in Sql Server Configuration Manager and it says port 1433. Could this be the problem?

I have been at this for hours and I have tried many different questions and read through many different questions and answers as well as many other forums.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1k00z82u4OI This video has answers which I tried.

In Visual Studio I am able to test the connection to my Database in Sql Server and it succeeds as well as provides me with the connection string for my SqlConnection object.

My server is listening on port 1434.

In Sql Server Configuration Mananger I have Shared Memory, (Named Pipes and TCP/IP enabled. I restarted SQL Server Browser, SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER), SQL Server Agent and they are running.

In Visual Studio my Data Connections is connected to my server and database and the State is Open.

My connection string looks like this (minus the actual characters of my server):

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source = DESKTOP - #######; Initial Catalog = ASPCRUD; Integrated Security = True;");
```

Error message includes:(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]

Comment: Assuming that you have no other SQL Server installations in the machine, can you try by changing the Data Source value to "(local)" instead of "DESKTOP - ######"?

Comment: @Martin why on earth did that work.................... I know for sure that I tried that more than a few times

Comment: I am not sure either. I just made a wild guess that there is some issue with the name resolution and asked you to check with (local).

Comment: I am not sure either. I just made a wild guess that there is some issue with the name resolution and asked you to check with (local). Happy to know that it has started working, anyway. :)